# SQL Как суммировать ячейки из одной строки с ячейкой из предыдущей строки с дополнительным условием для первой строки

Tags: sql, sql-server

есть данные по загрузке tbl1

есть данные по отгрузке tbl2

есть данные по остатку на складе на конец месяца tbl3

```
tbl1:                   tbl2:                       tbl3:
date        A           date        B               date        X   
01/06/23    7           01/06/23    5               01/06/23    6
02/06/23    9           02/06/23    6               
03/06/23    3           03/06/23    7               
04/06/23    8           04/06/23    6               
05/06/23    6           05/06/23    8
```

Необходимо рассчитывать остаток на складе на конец дня:

для С1 это X+A1-B1

для С2 и далее это C1+A2-B2

**ожидаемый результат**:

```
id  date        A   B   C
1   01/06/23    7   5   8
2   02/06/23    9   6   11
3   03/06/23    3   7   7
4   04/06/23    8   6   9
5   05/06/23    6   8   7
```

как такое можно сделать на ms sql?

Comment: почитать про оконные функции а-ля `LAG`, если версия СУБД не совсем древняя, то вроде должно быт не сложно. в первую строку подставить значения из `x`

Comment: нечто вроде `c = a + b - ISNULL(LAG(c) OVER ORDER BY date ASC, x)`. Сортировка окна, очевидно, должна совпадать с сортировкой всего запроса

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Пункты 5 и 3.

Comment: *есть данные по остатку на складе на конец месяца tbl3* А если смотреть на даты - то кагбэ на начало месяца...

Comment: Вопрос сформулирован понятно, нужно отвечать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант:

```
SELECT tA.Cnt as id, tbl1.opdate AS date, tbl1.A, tB.B, tX.X+tA.TOTA-tB.TOTB AS C    
FROM ((tbl1 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT tbl1.opdate AS D, SUM(t.A) AS TOTA, Count(t.A) AS Cnt
    FROM tbl1 INNER JOIN
      tbl1 AS t ON t.opdate<=tbl1.opdate
        AND t.opdate>=datefromparts(year(tbl1.opdate),month(tbl1.opdate),1)
    GROUP BY tbl1.opdate) AS tA ON tbl1.opdate=tA.D)
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT tbl2.opdate AS D, SUM(t.B) AS TOTB, tbl2.B
    FROM tbl2 INNER JOIN
      tbl2 AS t ON t.opdate<=tbl2.opdate
        AND t.opdate>=datefromparts(year(tbl2.opdate),month(tbl2.opdate),1)
    GROUP BY tbl2.opdate, tbl2.B) AS tB ON tbl1.opdate=tB.D)
  INNER JOIN tbl3 AS tX ON year(tX.opdate)=year(tbl1.opdate)
      and month(tX.opdate)=month(tbl1.opdate)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d2319/2)

В таблицах заменил date на opdate.

Comment: Спасибо большое))))